# Восстановление загрузчика Windows

Tags: windows-7, загрузка

Проблема заключается в том, что система не загружается без установочной флешки. Выдает "сбой при загрузке системы". Еще любопытная вещь в том, что при каждой перезагрузке нужно зайти в биос и просто сохранится и выйти (без внесения каких-либо изменений), иначе та же ошибка.
Пробовал все способы, которые только находил. И восстановление, и через командную строку и через безопасный режим. Все без толку. Переустановка ситуацию не меняет. Если кто знает какие-то другие методы - прошу помочь. Спасибо

Comment: если достаточно зайти в биос, то может быть батарейка просела? Хотя бы попробовал поправить в биосе загрузочное устройство.

Comment: Вы издеваетесь?

Comment: просевшая батарейка может выдавать самые разнообразные спецэффекты. Если используется UEFI, то вполне может быть, что флешка прописана туда загрузочным устройством. В этом случае ищите редакторы UEFI и загрузившись, фиксите.

Comment: А по подробней про фикс записи UEFI можно?

Comment: в uefi есть загрузочные записи. Их может быть много. Скорее всего туда прописалась левая/неверная. У меня было такое после переезда на ssd - система хотела старый диск в в кармане. Фиксил этим https://www.boyans.net/ и много-много черной магии.

Comment: Спасибо, будем пробовать